# If $M$ is a $2n$-dimensional simply connected compact oriented Riemannian manifold, then isometries on $M$ preserving orientation have a fixed point

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, fixed-points

These are original conditions on $M$, $M$ is a $2n$-dimensional compact orientable Riemannian manifold with positive sectional curvature, $\phi:M\rightarrow M$ is an isometry that preserves orientation.

Using Synge's theorem, we know that $M$ is simply-connected, $\phi$ is a degree $1$ map and $\phi_*:H_k(M)\rightarrow H_k(M)$ is an isomorphism, but this is still far from using Lefschetz's fixed point theory, and I don't have any idea on this problem.

Comment: If your map is an isometry, all of the $\phi_*$ should be identity matrices so $\operatorname{tr} \phi_*$ should just be the rank of the given cohomology group. Since the dimension is even, $H^0$ and $H^{2n}$ will both have the same sign when computing the Lefschetz number, so that's a contribution of $2$ right there. Simple connectedness gives $H^1 = H^{2n-1}=0$. Does positive sectional curvature have any additional consequences in terms of vanishing of middle cohomology?

Comment: Do you know how to prove Synge's theorem?

Comment: Assume $M$ has positive curvature. Then: (Sketch) Assume there is no fixed point, then there is $p\in M$ so that $d(p, \phi(p))$ is minimal. Let $\gamma$ be a minimal geodesic from $p$ to $\phi(p)$ of length $T=d(p, \phi(p))$. It is not hard to see $\phi_*(\gamma'(0))=\gamma'(T)$. Then $\phi_*$ is an isometry between the $(2n-1)$-dimensional planes  $\gamma'(0)^\perp$ and $\gamma'(T)^\perp$; the remaining uses the same argument as in Synge's theorem.